# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-adapter, fatal-error

Application is working fine at my side. After uploading to google play store this is what i am seeing in crashlytics of firebase. some users are experiencing crashes.  somebody help me plz :(

here is the Error i am experiencing:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's
> PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling
> PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 1,
> found: 2 Pager id: com.trendy.igProfileViewer:id/imagesPager Pager
> class: class com.stfalcon.imageviewer.common.pager.MultiTouchViewPager
> Problematic adapter: class
> com.stfalcon.imageviewer.viewer.adapter.ImagesPagerAdapter
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1143)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24855)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6893)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24855)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6893)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24855)
> at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
> at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24855)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6893)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24855)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6893)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24855)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.AlertDialogLayout.tryOnMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:134)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.AlertDialogLayout.onMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:64)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24855)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6893)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24855)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6893)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24855)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6893)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24855)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6893)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24855)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6893)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
> at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:773)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24855)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3117)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2652)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1819)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7781)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1031)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:854)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:789)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1016)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)

Comment: did you check following answers

Comment: This is the key `Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 1, found: 2`
Check why page adapter is changing with those values

Comment: @isthemartin yeah but how to fix that? its beyond my knowledge now. i tried everything :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943658/illegalstateexception-the-applications-pageradapter-changed-the-adapters-cont

Comment: Can you add crashing code (fragment + adapter)

Comment: You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` whenever the data in the `RecyclerView` is altered.